# Double parseDouble ignoring addition(+) sign which is part of the string

Tags: java

I am trying to convert string to double. String has plus sign in it which is not returned in the parsed string.

```
String s = "+12.350";
Double parsedString = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Output

```
12.350
```

It works fine if the string has "-" in it.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Please provide the actual code.

Comment: What would you expect the output to be?

Comment: Remember that `parseDouble` returns a `double`, which is only a value -- it doesn't specify the formatting for that value. `+12.350` is not different from `12.350`. They're exactly the same value, and so have the exact same `double` representation. The default formatting for doubles doesn't include a prefix `+` for positive numbers, but that's just a formatting option.

Comment: Code doesn't work and why is the '+' important?

Comment: because i need it in my application. Signs(+, -) are part of the output

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("+#,###0.000;-#");
String s = "+12.350";
Double parsedString = Double.parseDouble(s);
System.out.println(fmt.format(parsedString)); // +12.350

s = "-12.350";
parsedString = Double.parseDouble(s);
System.out.println(fmt.format(parsedString)); // -12.350
```

**[Java IdeOne example](https://ideone.com/loT824)**

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble(s);`
returns a double not a string, your code is not compiling...

for the convertions use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String s = "+12.350";
double parsedString = Double.parseDouble(s);
System.out.println(parsedString);
double pi = 3.1415;
String parsedDouble = String.valueOf(pi);
System.out.println(parsedDouble);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, positive doubles will never have the plus sign in front of them. If the string has a minus sign, the double will also carry the minus sign, as is traditional when you write the number (ie. You write -4.5 but not +4.5). If you want the plus sign, you have to add it on to the beginning as a string:

```
System.out.println((parsedString > 0) ? "+" : "" + parsedString);
```

However, this code should not compile anyway since `Double.parseDouble()` returns a double, not a String so `String parsedString = Double.parseDouble(s);` should not work since you are trying to make a double into a String.